# Checking for interfering timespans in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, datetime

I have a form where I can enter a beginning time and an ending time for a reservation in a restaurant. Now I want to check, if there already exists a reservation in my database which interferes with the timespan I have entered in the form. How can I do that?

Comment: This question is way to broad. Please ask a more specific question for example if you have tried something and it is not working post the code and ask why it's not working...

Comment: `Ajax` would be a good place to start...

Answer (score 1):

Client Validation:

1. Times are compatible with the open-for-business hours of your
   selected restaurant.
2. Times provided are a valid reservation: 'From' and 'To' are not reversed and leave enough time to order, prepare and dine (is this restaurant-dependent).

Assuming the client validation is passed call server API with the reservation request. Server should respond with appropriate error.

As an added user experience benefit the server should also be able to provide the client with a list of available reservation windows, so that a customer doesn't have to brute force his reservation till it passes the availability check.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for how to talk to API. If you are using AngularJS or another framework check the documentation for communicating with external resources, as well as cross domain communication.